# Purescript Halogen Input Element and Custom Autocorrect Property

Tags: html, safari, purescript, halogen

I'm trying to disable autocorrect in inputs for safari on iOS. There isn't currently an "autocorrect" property in purescript halogen, so I created one, and modified the indexed input element record to use it.

My problem is that the new property isn't actually added to the dom when the input element is rendered. I also created an "autocapitalize" property that is properly added to the dom when rendered in chrome, but not safari, so I know that the way I'm creating properties **can** work (though i'm not sure why neither property works in safari). I can add the "autocorrect" property with purescript-jquery and everything works in safari, but is there a more natural way to get the property in the DOM?

Here's the reference to the safari-specific "autocorrect" property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input.

I also created a github repo with the code https://github.com/sportanova/purescript-input-example/tree/master

I'm using purescript v0.8.5 and halogen v0.8

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Halogen
import Halogen.Util (awaitBody, runHalogenAff)
import Halogen.HTML.Properties.Indexed as PI
import Halogen.HTML.Elements as E
import Halogen.HTML.Indexed as HI
import Data.Generic (class Generic, gCompare, gEq)
import Control.Monad.Aff (Aff)
import Halogen.HTML.Core (Prop, prop, propName, attrName)
import Halogen.HTML.Elements.Indexed (Leaf)
import Halogen.HTML.Properties.Indexed (IProp, I)
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Control.Monad.Eff.JQuery as J

inputx :: forall p i. Leaf (accept :: I,  autocapitalize :: I, autocomplete :: I, autocorrect :: I, autofocus :: I, checked :: I, disabled :: I, form :: I, formaction :: I, formenctype :: I, formmethod :: I, formnovalidate :: I, formtarget :: I, height :: I, list :: I, max :: I, min :: I, multiple :: I, onAbort :: I, onChange :: I, onError :: I, onInput :: I, onInvalid :: I, onLoad :: I, onSearch :: I, onSelect :: I, pattern :: I, placeholder :: I, readonly :: I, required :: I, size :: I, src :: I, step :: I, inputType :: I, value :: I, width :: I) p i
inputx = unsafeCoerce E.input

refine :: forall a r i. (a -> Prop i) -> a -> IProp r i
refine = unsafeCoerce

onOffProp :: forall i. String -> Boolean -> Prop i
onOffProp pName = prop (propName pName) (Just $ attrName pName) <<< (\b -> if b then "on" else "off")

autoCapitalizeP :: forall i. Boolean -> Prop i
autoCapitalizeP = onOffProp "autocapitalize"

autocapitalize :: forall r i. Boolean -> IProp (autocapitalize :: I | r) i
autocapitalize = refine autoCapitalizeP

autoCorrectP :: forall i. Boolean -> Prop i
autoCorrectP = onOffProp "autocorrect"

autocorrect :: forall r i. Boolean -> IProp (autocorrect :: I | r) i
autocorrect = refine autoCorrectP


type State = { }

data Query a =
    Initialize a
  | Finalize a

ui :: forall eff. Component State Query (ExEff eff)
ui = lifecycleComponent {
  render,
  eval,
  initializer: Just (action Initialize),
  finalizer: Just (action Finalize)
} where

  render :: State -> ComponentHTML Query
  render st = HI.div_
    [
      HI.div_ [HI.text "autocorrect attribute not added"]
    , inputx
        [
          PI.name "example"
        , PI.autocomplete false
        , autocorrect false
        , autocapitalize false
        , PI.spellcheck false
        , PI.inputType PI.InputText
        ]
    , HI.div_ [HI.text "autocorrect attribute added through jquery"]
    , inputx
      [
        PI.name "working-example"
      , PI.id_ "working-example"
      , PI.autocomplete false
      , autocorrect false
      , autocapitalize false
      , PI.spellcheck false
      , PI.inputType PI.InputText
      ]
    ]

  eval :: Natural Query (ComponentDSL State Query (ExEff eff))
  eval (Initialize next) = do
    inputEl <- fromEff $ J.select ("#working-example")
    x <- fromEff $ J.setAttr "autocorrect" "off" inputEl
    pure next
  eval (Finalize next) = pure next


data Slot = Slot

derive instance slotGeneric :: Generic Slot

instance eqSlot :: Eq Slot where
  eq = gEq

instance ordGeneric :: Ord Slot where
  compare = gCompare

type ExEff eff = Aff (EX eff)
type EX eff = HalogenEffects (eff)

main :: forall eff. Eff (EX eff) Unit
main = runHalogenAff do
  body <- awaitBody
  runUI ui {} body
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried defining these with the `Attr` constructor rather than `prop`? I think since they're not part of the standard DOM API they will need to be defined as plain attributes rather than as properties.

The attribute/property distinction is an unfortunate thing inherited from the DOM API - properties are special, basically, as they are part of the interface of the element and not necessarily string-typed in their values.

The other cause might be that there are properties for `autocorrect` and `autocapitalize`, but they are not named that way - property names are case sensitive, unlike attribute names.

[The `for` property](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/d6f86daabf96de7b1617b6fdc2a51491314963f5/src/Halogen/HTML/Properties.purs#L93-L94) is an example of a case where the property and attribute names differ.